# How to add multiple value using autocomplete widget

Tags: ajax

We create a input field using user interface for add multiple languages .How i can add multiple language using comma separate so after comma they will populate other language.

Answer (score -1):

You need to explode the string inside the `autocomplete` function.

```
function autocomplete_callback($string) {
  $explode_str = explode(',', $string);
  $last_str = drupal_strtolower(array_pop($explode_str));
  // use $last_str in the query
  $explode_str[] = $result;
  return implode($explode_str);
}
```

Comment: so can i copy paste them into autocomplete.module file

Comment: You need to change in query/validation/submit function.

Comment: Is that any module to add multiple value on single textbox via comma separated

Comment: You can check example code of core taxonomy module. Check `hook_menu` in `taxonomy.module`.

Comment: ok, i will try.